# Prediction at a new value using lowess function in R

Tags: r, loess

I am using `lowess` function to fit a regression between two variables `x` and `y`. Now I want to know the fitted value at a new value of `x`. For example, how do I find the fitted value at `x=2.5` in the following example. I know `loess` can do that, but I want to reproduce someone's plot and he used `lowess`.

```
set.seed(1)
x <- 1:10
y <- x + rnorm(x)
fit <- lowess(x, y)
plot(x, y)
lines(fit)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Local regression (lowess) is a non-parametric statistical method, it's a not like linear regression where you can use the model directly to estimate new values.

You'll need to take the values from the function (that's why it only returns a list to you), and choose your own interpolation scheme. Use the scheme to predict your new points.

Common technique is spline interpolation (but there're others):

https://www.r-bloggers.com/interpolation-and-smoothing-functions-in-base-r/

**EDIT**: I'm pretty sure the `predict` function does the interpolation for you. I also can't find any information about what exactly `predict` uses, so I've tried to trace the source code.

https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/af7f52f70101960861e5d995d3a4bec010bc89e6/src/library/stats/R/loess.R

```
else { ## interpolate
## need to eliminate points outside original range - not in pred_
```

I'm sure the R code calls the underlying C implementation, but it's not well documented so I don't know what algorithm it uses.

My suggestion is: either trust the `predict` function or roll out your own interpolation algorithm.

Comment: Thanks. In `loess`, you can use `cars.lo <- loess(dist ~ speed, cars);
predict(cars.lo, data.frame(speed = seq(5, 30, 1)), se = TRUE)` to get the prediction at a new value `x`. Do you happen to know what interpolation method is used here? I can't find it in its help file.

Comment: @PatrickLi As I explained, the function is doing interpolation for you. I'm looking what scheme it uses, once I found it, I'll update the answer.

Comment: @PatrickLi I tried to trace it, but not fully successful. Look at my EDITED.

Comment: Nonparametric locally weighted regression is a perfectly valid statistical model, just like parametric regression. Given a set of values {y_i, X_i}, you can obtain an estimated value of y for any new value of X. It just takes more work to code up.

Comment: An alternative solution is here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/126699/residuals-from-lowess-curve